# Rails sort dropdown list alphabetically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, user-interface, drop-down-menu

Respected ppl ....

Im using ransack to do searching in my application ...

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :hospital_cont , "Hospital Name"%>
  <%= f.select :hospital_id_eq, options_from_collection_for_select(Hospital.all, "id",   "hospital_name", @q.hospital_id_eq) %>


<div class="form-actions">
<%= f.submit "Search", :name => nil, :class => "btn" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

currently the above code produces a dropdown box of hospital names ... but it is sorted by id ...

Kindly tell how to sort it using hospital_names alphabetically ....

Thnx ....

Comment: the column in hospital is hospital_name, really? do you prepend everything or is it an accident?

Comment: Its not an accident ... it is the actual name ...
Sorry if its a design issue ...

Comment: I personaly don't really care but you're not doing yourself a favor.

Comment: Thnx for the advice :) ... im new with this ...still learning ... ill keep this tip in mind ....

Comment: just consider your code `hospital = Hospital.new` then `hospital.hospital_name`... `hospital.name` looks better

Comment: Oh u are right :) ...thnx again for the tip ...ill keep this in mind ....Regards

Comment: -1 because your question asked about sorting the list box, and you accepted an answer for sorting the source data.  Great if the source is sortable.  Rephrase the question to how to sort records from the database..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
Hospital.all
```

with:

```
Hospital.order("hospital_name")
```